# Shut down the monitor in a MacBook Pro, without to put it to sleep?

Tags: mac, macbook, display, sleep, macbook-pro

How do I set the monitor to shutdown in a MacBook Pro? I do not want the computer to stop running; I do not wish it to go to sleep.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to **System Preferences** > **Energy Saver** to set how long to wait before putting the computer to sleep. Pull the slider all the way to the right for *Never*. You can also adjust how long to wait before putting the display to sleep.

To set a Hot Corner to sleep the display, go to **System Preferences** > **Exposé & Spaces** > **Exposé** and set a corner to *Sleep Display*. Then just move your mouse pointer into the corner to sleep the display. (Thanks for reminding me of that, jmlumpkin.)

Comment: And you could also set up a hot corner that also will put the display to sleep as well.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to turn the display off quickly, you can hold down Shift-Control-Eject all together to sleep the display immediately.

Comment: Doesn't work for me out of the box?

Comment: works for me   . . .

Comment: @slhck Yes, it works right out of the box.

Comment: @jmlumpkin Weird, I don't recall having changed anything. Well, I'll try it on another machine tomorrow.

Comment: Can confirm that this works out of the box. MBP, OSX 10.6.7.

Comment: @slhck: It started doing this on Leopard; is it possible you're older than that?

Comment: @Ben No I'm on a brand new Macbook Pro. Works now, maybe I was too stupid to press the buttons correctly :P

Comment: Yah, this has been around for a bit, I think I remember using it before leopard, but not sure how much earlier than that.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I remember (hearing about) the introduction of it in Leopard, but I never really used Tiger so it's possible it was in Tiger as well. It's definitely not in Panther.

Answer (score 1):

CTRL - SHIFT - POWER will get you there.

Eject button doesn't exist on a Macbook Pro Retina and others...

Comment: Power button doesn't exist on new MacBook Pro